# Sending email when using Site Rules

Tags: outsystems

We have a website in Outsystems. 
The dutch ('nl') local uses the base url website.hosting.net
The english ('en') local uses the base url website.hosting.net/en

When I send an email from the dutch website everything goes ok.
When I send an email from the english website I get an error

```
Error creating Email. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OutSystems.HubEdition.RuntimePlatform.Email.EmailHelper.HttpGetContent(String ssUrl, String method, String contentType, String userAgent, Cookie cookie, QueryParameter[] parameters, String& ssContent, String& ssContentEncoding)
   at OutSystems.HubEdition.RuntimePlatform.Email.EmailHelper.HttpPost(String ssUrl, QueryParameter[] parameters, String userAgent, Cookie cookie, String& ssContent, String& ssContentEncoding)
   at OutSystems.HubEdition.RuntimePlatform.Email.EmailProcessor.SendEmailRequest(String url, String from, String to, String cc, String bcc, Int32 activityId, Int32 tenantId, Boolean storeContent, EmailType type) On 
   at OutSystems.HubEdition.RuntimePlatform.Email.EmailProcessor.SendEmailRequest(String url, String from, String to, String cc, String bcc, Int32 activityId, Int32 tenantId, Boolean storeContent, EmailType type)
   at myEspace.Flows.FlowMainFlow.myScreen.CommandCreateOrder(HeContext heContext)
```

How can I send email from other locales using the site Rules?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be some sort of configuration that may be very hard for you to get an accurate answer in this forum.

I would suggest that you reach out to [OutSystems Support](https://success.outsystems.com/Support).

Cheers!
Mario